# how to migrate Render Function with h() Arguments of vue into react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js

I am migrating my vue app to react app. So, in my vue application i am using render function with parameters returning the vnode which i used for icon modification purpose.
Now, i need some suggestions that how can i do this in react way?

**Here is the sample vue code**

```
render(h, {props, data,listeners, children = []}) {
   if (props.item) {
      const { first, last } = props;
      const reorderingClasses = Object.entries({ first, last })
        .filter(filterFalsy)
        .map(([key, value]) => `${key}-${value}`)
        .join(' ');

      const { xs, sm, md, lg } = props;
      const sizeClasses = Object.entries({ xs, sm, md, lg })
        .filter(filterFalsy)
        .map(
          ([key, value]) => `col-${key}${value !== 'auto' ? `-${value}` : ''}`
        )
        .join(' ');

     ..... some other code 
  }
   let iconName = props.icon || children.pop().text;
        let options = {
            class: [
                'my-icon',
                cType && 'my-icon--'+cType,
                cColor && 'my-icon--'+cColor,
                cSize &&'my-icon--'+cSize,
                props.spacing && 'my-icon--spacing'
            ],
            style: {
                fontSize: customSize
            },
            on: listeners
        };
        if(data.class) {
            if(Array.isArray(data.class)) {
                options.class = options.class.concat(data.class);
            }
            if(typeof data.class === 'string' || typeof data.class === 'object') {
                options.class.push(data.class);
            }
        }
        if(data.style) {
            options.style = Object.assign(data.style, options.style);
        }
    ....some code
    
    return h('i',Object.assign(data, options));
}
```

Here i am configuring vnode for icons. So, i need suggestion in react how to do this? Any suggestion will be helpful

Comment: What is the problem with this?

Comment: How to configure for children and listeners in react render function?

Comment: See https://reactjs.org/docs/react-without-jsx.html . React doesn't handle listeners specifically, the rest is quite common